# Rails 3 destroy method respond_with JS using nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, nested-routes

I'm having this annoying problem with Rails 3 (ruby 1.9.2) and nested resources. In my routes:

```
resources :lists do
  resources :items, only: [:destroy, :update, :create]
end
```

My `ItemsController` has `respond_to :json` at the beginning and `#destroy` looks like this:

```
def destroy
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  @item.destroy
  respond_with @list, @item
end
```

The link to destroy the item:

```
<%= link_to 'x', list_item_path(@list, item), method: :delete, remote: true %>
```

Which translates into correct html, like:

```
<a href="/lists/1/items/52" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">x</a>
```

When I click the link, my item is correctly deleted but the method always returns `{}`. I've been trying to tinker with it but can't get anything different from that empty JSON object!

Every other method (`#create` and `#update`) works and returns JSON objects as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what else you would expect it to do.  If the `item` is deleted, the JSON response will be empty since it can't return a destroyed object.

With `create` and `update`, the `item` object still exists so it will return that as a JSON hash.

Comment: I believe that's not correct. The item is deleted on the DB but the `@item` object still exists. Also, if I comment the `@item.destroy` line it doesn't even delete the record from the DB and still returns {}

Comment: Ok so I kept my investigation on this issue and you are almost right. If it was a GET then I would get the object, but when you use DELETE or PUT rails only allows you to get {} and status OK as response.